# How do I add a span in a link_to with an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

So I have this:

```ruby
<%= link_to(image_tag(@model.picture.url(:thumb), :alt => ''), "/pages/you/#{something.id}", {:id => "y_link_#{something.id}"}) %>
```

Which works, but I need a span in between also like this:

```html
 <a id="y_link_2" href="/pages/you/2" class="">
     <span>Apples</span>
     <img src="another_small.jpg?1236340989" alt="">
 </a>
```

How do I add

```html
 <span>Apples</span>
```

to the `link_to`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`image_tag` and `content_tag` return basic strings, so they can be concatenated using the `+` operator easily:

`<%= link_to(content_tag(:span, "Apples") + image_tag(@model.picture.url(:thumb), :alt => ''), "/pages/you/#{something.id}", {:id => "y_link_#{something.id}"}) %>`

However, as you can see, it gets quite messy - might be worth moving it into a helper method.

Answer (score 19):

Feed a block to your link_to call:

```
<% link_to("/pages/you/#{something.id}", {:id => "y_link_#{something.id}"}) do %>
  <%= content_tag(:span, 'Apples') %>
  <%= image_tag(@model.picture.url(:thumb), :alt => '') %>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively:

```
<% link_to("/pages/you/#{something.id}", {:id => "y_link_#{something.id}"}) do %>
  <span>Apples</span>
  <%= image_tag(@model.picture.url(:thumb), :alt => '') %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a path, use the structure like so

```
<%= link_to edit_section_path(@section) do %>
   Edit
   <span class="fa fa-list pull-right"></span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Haml](http://haml.info) lends itself well to situations like these. For example:

```
= link_to "/pages/you/#{something.id}", id: "y_link_#{something.id} do
    %span Apples
    = image_tag(@model.picture.url(:thumb), alt: '')
```

[Alternatively](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#object_reference_):

```
%a[something, 'y_link']{href: "/pages/you/#{something.id}"}
    %span Apples
    %img{src: @model.picture.url(:thumb)}
```

It's worth learning if you want to write your views faster and read them better.